# How to conditionally process records in a loop

Tags: loops, vbscript

I'm struggling with the transition from a C# continue statement in VBS.  I have a simple recordset returned, and I know that there are 8 records in the dev recordset.  I only want to display those with status equal to "NEW".

I set my DO loop up like this, but I'm only getting a portion of the correct records in the recordset.  Is this the most efficient way to break out of the recordset loop and skip records that don't match my criteria?

```
Do Until rs.EOF

  Do 
    If rs("status") = "EXISTING" Then Exit Do 
    Loop While False 

    [Do Stuff]

    rs.MoveNext
  Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

The requirement you listed can be coded directly and it'd be similar in VBScript and C#.

```
Do Until rs.EOF
    If rs("status") = "NEW" Then

        [Do Stuff]

    End If

    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```